# Use headers and libraries from different folders

Tags: macos, linker, vala

I have two GTK builds on my Mac, an X11 one with headers and a Quartz one without. I can compile Vala code for X11 just fine, but how do I use the Quartz libraries?

This is probably a C question, but I only ever used that toolchain through valac.

Answer (score 2):

When using valac, it gets the appropriate compile and link flags from pkg-config based on the `--pkg` flags. You can see what is being included with `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0`. If you wish to change this you have two opions:

1. Use `valac -C` to only produce C files and manage the compilation and linking yourself.
2. Set `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/sw/lib/pkgconfig` or whatever collection of directories to get your packages coming in the desired order.

I'm not quite sure where your GTK+ installs are located, presumably in a MacPorts tree.

Comment: The Quartz build has no pkgconfig metadata, but I was able to modify the output from your command. Basically keep the `-I` and change all the `-L` while adjusting some `-l` to account for minor version differences.